# Is this set recursively enumerable?

Tags: computer-science, computability

Let $A=\{e: \varphi_e$ is total and $\forall x(\varphi_e(x)\leq\varphi_e(x+1))\}$, where $\varphi_e$ denotes the $e$-th recursive function.

I'm trying to show that the previous set is recursively enumerable, since I've already proved that it is not recursive. My attempt has been to express it as an intersection of $B=\{e: \varphi_e$ is total$\}$ and $C=\{e:\forall x(\varphi_e(x)\leq\varphi_e(x+1))\}$. I know that $B$ is recursively enumerable, and I think $C$ is as well, but I don't know how to show it, because as far as I know $\forall x P(x)$ is not a recursive predicate in general even when $P(x)$ is recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ is **not** recursively enumerable. While for any fixed $k$, we can wait and see whether $\varphi_e(k)$ halts - and so for any fixed $k$, the set $\{e: \varphi_e(k)$ halts$\}$ is r.e. - this fails when we consider *infinitely many* $k$ at once.

The intuition here is just to think about the task at hand: if I'm playing around with a Turing machine $\varphi_e$, how can I be sure that it's total after examining it for only finitely much time? At best I can see $\varphi_e$ halt on finitely many inputs, but it could still fail to halt on others.

In fact, $B$ has Turing degree $0''$ - strictly more complicated than the halting problem.

---

In fact, you can reduce $B$ to the set you're interested in (and so it's not r.e.): do you see a way to transform a computable partial function $f$ into a computable partial function $\hat{f}$ such that $f$ is total iff $\hat{f}$ is total and nondecreasing?

Comment: @Javi You think you've done what before?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter before I ended the comment!

Comment: @Javi What are $g$ and $f'$ here? Also, what does the subscript "$LT(...)$" mean? I think this is going in the right direction but it's not clear to me right now.

Comment: I think I've done that before. I'm not sure if my notation is standard so I'm going to explain it: I denote $[a_1,\dots,a_n]=\prod_{i=1}^np_i$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime number.

Then I can recursively define
$$
\begin{align*}
&\hat{f}(0)=[f(0)]\\
&\hat{f}(x+1)=f(x+1)*\hat{f}(x)
\end{align*}
$$
Where by $*$ I mean concatenation and $Lt$ denotes the lenght of $[a_1,\dots,_a_n]$ which is $n$. Would that work?

Comment: @Javi That second approach is easier.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the mess